# Run time error 13: Type Mismatch (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2010

I'm getting a Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch every time I run this code. It's supposed to clear three columns of cells, move over the next three columns and then clear another three until it runs out of columns with values. The Error is appearing on the `Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""` line.

```
Sub Blanker()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("BCF3").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(106, 2)).Select
        Selection.Clear
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select        
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using a loop to do something what appears to be just one time. Try this:

```
Sub Blanker()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("BCF3").Select
If ActiveCell.Value <> vbNullString Then
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(106, 2)).Select
    Selection.Clear
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's clearing 3 columns of cells several times (I have tons of columns of data). At least that's what I'm trying to do. The code you posted gave the same error.

Comment: I missed that last offset at the bottom, my mistake.  I tried your code on a new blank workbook where I through some random values in it, and it is working for me.  Does VBA tell you where specifically you're having this error pop up?

Comment: It highlights the line Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "", I'll try moving the data to a blank workbook. Edit: Blank Workbook didn't work for me.

Comment: Got it working! I had some non-numerical place holders for data that didn't exist that i replaced with 0, after that it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code didn't work with non-numerical values. Specifically #VALUE!. I changed all instances of #VALUE! to 0 and the code worked.